# C# ListView Column Empty

Tags: c#, listview

Okay so I'm currently trying to fill in some empty listview columns.

First of all I'll show you the image.

[image: I've put the empty columns with highlighted edges.]

So as you can see by this image, I have some empty columns.

I've custom named these columns.

cVerified
cApi
cReseller

now what I'm trying to do is.

If cVerified has an empty column it will write N/A in the box instead of just leaving it blank.

If cApi has an empty column it will write False in the box instead of just leaving it blank.

If cReseller has an empty column it will write N/A in the box instead of just leaving it blank.

Hope you understand.

Comment: Let me ask first, How do you fill the listview? can you show the code.

Comment: it's adding them from my html source and adding them to the listview with this code.

Comment: account.SubItems.Add(ct.validated);
                    account.SubItems.Add(ct.apiuser);
                    account.SubItems.Add(ct.resellername);

Comment: Is **account** initialized correctly for every row?

Comment: yes but some data doesn't contain any text, this is why I'm wanting to fill it in from the code side of things instead. I just need a code for my custom column if it's empty it will display N/A as text.

Comment: if(account.SubItems(ct.validated) = null ) {
var x = "N/A";
account.SubItems(x);
}
This code is not tested, but I hope it gives you an idea

Comment: the code has some errors.

Comment: error is non-invocable member can not be used as a method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing something like

```
...
item1.SubItems.Add(obj.cVerified);
item1.SubItems.Add(obj.cApi );
item1.SubItems.Add(obj.cReseller);
...
```

Then you're best bet is to do some data validation on the back end, either in the object properties itself, like so:

```
public class obj
{
    private string _cReseller;
    public string cReseller
    {
        get
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(_cReseller) ? "N/A" : _cReseller;
        }
        set
        {
            _cReseller = value;
        }
    }

    //...You can put the other two properties below
}
```

Or you can do it with a separate function.

```
private static string GetDefaultText(string param)
{
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(param) ? "N/A" : param;
}
```

Pick the option that fits your coding pattern.

Soon, you can learn to [bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bindingcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) data to a list view and get rid of that gnarly logic altogether.

Comment: okat well that didn't work any of those. Here is how I'm capturing the data from the html file if that helps.

Comment: JObject ob = JObject.Parse(html);
                    ob = JObject.Parse(html);
                    Console.WriteLine(html);
                    ct.validated = (string)ob["errortexts"]["not_validated"];
                    ct.apiuser = (string)ob["errortexts"]["api_user"];
                    ct.resellername = (string)ob["errortexts"]["reseller_name"];
                    Console.WriteLine(ct.validated);
                    Console.WriteLine(ct.apiuser);
                    Console.WriteLine(ct.resellername);

Comment: @JohnDueDueDue First, "That didn't work any of those" is about as helpful as it is grammatically correct. Why did it not work? Second, this solution will work for you if your code is formed properly. For example, ct.validated and ct.apiuser should be boolean objects. Not strings.

Comment: Well it didn't add anything to the listview if the column for cValidated was empty.

Comment: @JohnDueDueDue You need to research how to properly populate a listview. If you just want to copy paste code, go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and copy that example. Understand it, then ask questions about it

Comment: I still don't get it and I learn best from others. I'm not trying to copy and paste.